# Showing empty space for integer

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
String s1 = sh.getString("name", "");
int a = sh.getInt("age", 0);
```

For this code I would like to show empty spaces for s1 and a if there is no input entered. When I run the application String s1 it shows empty space but int a showd 0 since the default value is 0.

Is there any way to show empty space instead of 0?

I have tried puting

```
Integer.parseInt("")
```

But it was not working.

Is there any solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Where will you show the empty space? if you will show it inside text view then just add a ternary condition or something else. For example: textView.setText(a == 0 ? "" : a);

Comment: @Farhan you need to add `String.valueOf()` to set an int value to a textView.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to check if it is 0 or not. Using `null` as suggested by answer by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71491495/17133283) can be used but it is not preferred. Instead you can try this:

```
String text = a == 0 ? "" : String.valueOf(a);
textView.setText(text);
button.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just n need to parse it as string you can't check empty if you are using int variable So just get your age as String and also send it with string via intent you can also parse it as int after getting it from intent

Like option 1

```
Intent intent =new Intent(this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("name", name);
intent.putExtra("age", age.toString);
```

Here you can get Like

```
String s1 = sh.getString("name", "");
String age= sh.getString("age", "");
```

Here you can check age is empty then if you want this value as int you can Parse it as `int a=Integer.parseInt(age);`

Hope this will help you